# Authentication with Angular 5

Tags: authentication, angular5, auth-guard

I have a login page and I need to go to my home page after successful login. That login functionality login to a ldap server and send a response whether the authentication is success or not. I don't want that to keep in localstorage since this app has only two pages. login and home. When login success it should redirect to home page, if not it should redirect to again to the login page.

And please the console.log in the browser, "inside auth guard true" prints thousands times..

The only code I have in my app.component.html is `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

[image: app.module.ts]

[image: login.component.ts]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the canActivate(), all you need to do is return true or false. When you are redirecting it to home from inside the function you are entering into an infinite loop.

This is because on redirecting to home the canActivate() gets called and its expects a boolean return value. If the value is false, it won't load the component.

```
canActivate() {
        if (this.authService.loggedIn) {
            console.log('Inside Auth Gaurd');
            return true;
        }
        console.log('auth gaurd false path');
        return false;
    }
```

For more detail on canActivate() refer [this](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: Thanks Rachit but it doesn't solve my problem. I still can't redirect once the authentication succeeds. It just stays in the login page. In the console.log it says 'success' in the browser.

Comment: I just fixed. It just a silly mistake i did in the AuthGuard service. It must return true inside the if condition.